# Como centralizar uma div embaixo de outra, ultrapassando o limite da primeira?

Tags: html, css, css3

Olá, estou aprendendo sobre CSS3 e estou tentando centralizar uma div embaixo da outra para que fique mais ou menos dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo a a minha tem ficado dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar os margin-bottom: -150px
Não funcionou. E eu também tenho dúvida sobre se eu forçar em pixel não quebrar em layouts diferentes.

Meu código é esse:

```
<body>
  <div class="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  body {
    background: black;
  }

  .aaa {
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #c72523;
    position: relative;
  }

  .bbb {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  }

  .a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue aqui uma opção, como vc está usando `position absolut` na `div` dos link, use `bottom` e `left` e depois `transform:translate` para centralizar na base como vc quer. Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo.

*Exiba em página toda para ver melhor o resultado*

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.aaa {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #c72523;
  position: relative;
}

.bbb {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: auto;

  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```